# Why doesn't comparison between numeric and character variables give a warning?

Tags: r

I had a bug in my code resulting from an inadvertent comparison between a character variable and a numeric variable (they were both supposed to be numeric). This bug would have been much easier to find if R had a warning when doing this type of comparison. For example, why does this not throw a warning

```
> 'two' < 5
[1] FALSE
```

but this does throw a warning

```
> as.numeric('two') < 5
[1] NA
Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

It is not clear to me what is going on behind the scenes in the first comparison?

Comment: the warning is not coming from the comparison, but rather from `as.numeric`

Comment: The answer is that this is R (designed to be mostly compatible with S),  and not C, Java, or whatever other language you expected it to be. There is quite a bit of coercion of types that occurs and not just with comparison operators. It's just not a strongly typed language.

Comment: @Dwin I do appreciate that R does its best to make sense of my code, but with something as nonsensical as 'two' < 5, I just hoped R would warn me. I wish there were an option that could be turned on that would cause a warning to be printed to the screen for this type of thing (e.g. gcc -Wall).

Comment: @Dan you can always write your own validation lines of code.  E.g. `if(!is.numeric(data_1) | !is.numeric(data_2) {do something appropriate}`

Comment: "Nonsensical" comes from your mental model of how computers should interpret strings. Is it nonsense to compare "two" and "three" and find  that it is the latter that is lower? Why is it wrong to compare "11" to "9" and find that it is the former that is lower? comparisons of strings use alpha order. Fairly simple, even if it seems "nonsensical".

Comment: @DanFortin, there are many advantages to comparing objects of different types.  The flexibility comes at a cost in that the onus is more heavily placed on the user. But as Carl appropriately points out, this is easy to handle.

Comment: @Dwin I agree that 'nonsensical' is subjective, I guess it's just my view that if R wants to change "11" < 9 to "11" < "9" in order to do the comparison, R should let me know that is what it's doing. I'm not advocating that this should be an error, just a friendly "Warning: converting numeric to character" or something to this effect.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In your example `5` is converted to a character, so the test is the same as `'two' < as.character(5)`.

From `?Comparison`:

> If the two arguments are atomic vectors of different types, one is
>   coerced to the type of the other, the (decreasing) order of precedence
>   being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw.

Comment: Thanks! I had a hard time finding documentation on this topic.

Comment: For documentation on functions that contain non-alphanumeric characters, enclose it in backticks `?\`<\``  or use the help function with quotes:  `help("<")`     .

Comment: @RicardoSaporta or use `?"<"`