# Dot as a string comparison to a number

Tags: r, logical-operators

Can someone explain this behaviour **^**:

```
class(".")
# [1] "character"

as.numeric(".")
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
#  NAs introduced by coercion 

as.numeric(".") == 0
# [1] NA
# Warning message:
#   NAs introduced by coercion 

"." < 0
# [1] TRUE

"." == 0
# [1] FALSE

"." > 0
# [1] FALSE
```

I think this is about [NSE](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html), but can't think why would this not error out: `"." > 0`

**^** If this is a dupe please point it out, not that easy to search for a dot.

---

**EDIT:**

OK, this is a dupe, here is an example why this is happening:

```
"." < 0.5
# [1] TRUE

"." < as.character(0.5)
# [1] TRUE

order(c(".",  "0.5"))
# [1] 1 2
```

Comment: Interesting question, here's a related post.  [Why doesn't comparison between numeric and character variables give a warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19009936)

Comment: Why downvote, care to explain? Question is clear with examples, and it is already marked as duplicate, how else could we improve this post?