# Substitute p values for stars in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, substitution, p-value

I have a `data.frame` `dfP` with a column `Spearman_p` that contains p values (numeric data). I would like to substitute them for p value summary stars. I use this code:

```
 dfP$Spearman_p[dfP$Spearman_p < 0.0001] <- "****"
 dfP$Spearman_p[dfP$Spearman_p < 0.001] <- "***"
 dfP$Spearman_p[dfP$Spearman_p < 0.01] <- "**"
 dfP$Spearman_p[dfP$Spearman_p < 0.05] <- "*"
 dfP$Spearman_p[dfP$Spearman_p > 0.05] <- "ns"
```

However, this changes **all** p values <0.05 (so also those <0.01) to * (one star).

I suspect that R considers **** as a numeric <0.05 in subsequent steps. Is that correct? If so, how can I circumvent this, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the following function. It changes the entire vector in one go.

```
makeStars <- function(x){
  stars <- c("****", "***", "**", "*", "ns")
  vec <- c(0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 1)
  i <- findInterval(x, vec)
  stars[i]
}

dfP$Spearman_p <- makeStars(dfP$Spearman_p)
```

But maybe it's better if you create a new vector.

```
dfP$Spearman_p_stars <- makeStars(dfP$Spearman_p)
```

Comment: @SylviaRodriguez Sorry for the stupid mistake, will edit. Done.

Comment: Fantastic! Awesome solution. Thanks for the edit too.

Comment: This solution has uneven lengths for `stars` and `vecs`.  The fn `findInterval` by default is zero-indexed, FYI.  FOR me, `cuts =c(0.001, 0.01, 0.05, 0.10, 1)` and `stars=c("***", "**", "*", ".", "N.S.")` works with `idx = 1 + findInterval(pvals, cuts, left.open=TRUE)` and `stars[idx]`

Comment: @mshaffer `findInterval` is not zero-indexed, only if the `pvals` have values outside the range of `vec` (`cuts` in your comment). But unlike your `cuts` vector, my `vec` starts at 0 and there are no p-values less than zero. The uneven lengths are deliberate, a cuts vector of length `n` defines `n-1` intervals and that's the length of the stars vector.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative: use `stars.pval()` from the `gtools` package.

[Documentation here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtools/versions/3.5.0/topics/stars.pval).

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you do the first substitution, you transform the vector `dfP$Spearman_p` into a character vector. When comparing character vectors `"***"` (or any number of stars) is smaller than 0.05 and thus the expression is evaluated to `TRUE` and `"***"` is substituted by `"*"`.

See also: [Why doesn't comparison between numeric and character variables give a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009936/why-doesnt-comparison-between-numeric-and-character-variables-give-a-warning)

I suggest to create a new column, i.e. `Spearman_p_sign`:

```
dfP$Spearman_p_sign <- "ns"
dfP$Spearman_p_sign[dfP$Spearman_p < 0.0001] <- "****"
dfP$Spearman_p_sign[dfP$Spearman_p < 0.001] <- "***"
dfP$Spearman_p_sign[dfP$Spearman_p < 0.01] <- "**"
dfP$Spearman_p_sign[dfP$Spearman_p < 0.05] <- "*"
```

or you could work with nested `ifelse`, or the `case_when`-function from the `dplyr`-package.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation and solution. 2x awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I found this question quite interesting as it appears `Ops` group has an unique behaviour when used together with the `<=`.

When comparing a `character` variable and a `numeric` variable would normally yield `FALSE`, e.g:

```
> "a" < 1
[1] FALSE
> "a" < 10
[1] FALSE
> "a" < 100
[1] FALSE
```

However, realised that this wasn't the case with operators (`Ops` group). e.g.

```
> "*" < 1
[1] TRUE
> "*" < 10
[1] TRUE
> "*" < 100
[1] TRUE
> "*" < 0.1
[1] TRUE
```

Not sure why as `"*"` still returns a `character`..

```
> "+" < 0.1
[1] TRUE
> "+" < 100
[1] TRUE
```

Rui Barradas's solution works and this is another way you could do, first converting into a letter then convert the letter to `*`

```
test <- data.frame(col1 = c("A", "B", "C"), 
                   col2 = c(0.04, 0.009, 0.0009), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

test$new[test$col2 < 0.05] <- "a"
test$new[test$col2 < 0.01] <- "aa"
test$new[test$col2 < 0.001] <- "aaa"

test$new2 <- gsub("a", "*", test$new)

  col1   col2 new new2
1    A 0.0400   a    *
2    B 0.0090  aa   **
3    C 0.0009 aaa  ***
```

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for the insights and solution.