# Comparing strings to numeric

Tags: r, comparison

When I write the following code

```
"hello" > 9
```

It is assessed as `TRUE`. Why is that the case? What is the coercion that happens in the background for R to assess this as `TRUE`?

I was thinking 9 would be coerced to '9' but didn't know how R establishes the order of strings.

```
"Hello" > 9
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Your instinct is right -- c.f. `'hello' > '9'`. You can read `?"<"` for more on how string comparison is done -- "Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic..."

Comment: but why does 'hello' > '9' gets evaluated to TRUE is the real question I am trying to answer.

Comment: See edit; in general it is a very complicated issue, but the basic idea is, lexicographically

Comment: not sure it's a dupe - while it's a bit unclear/mixed-together, part of this question seems to ask how the order is determined after the coercion ...

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009936/why-doesnt-comparison-between-numeric-and-character-variables-give-a-warning

Answer (score 5):

You're right that `>` coerces the number to a string before comparing.

`?">"` says:

> Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within
>        the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use: see
>        ‘locales’.  The collating sequence of locales such as ‘en_US’ is
>        normally different from ‘C’ (which should use ASCII) and can be
>        surprising.

*Lexicographic order* means letter-by-letter comparison as in a dictionary; one often-surprising result of this is that "10"<"2".

Interpreting this, it means that whether "9" is greater or less than "H" in your example will depend on where "9" and "H" fall in the *collating sequence* (the internal order of symbols/letters/numbers etc.)

The end of `example(">")` generates a table of the collating sequence: on my machine, you can see that the numbers come before all of the letters ...

```
writeLines(strwrap(paste(sort(x), collapse=" "), width = 60))
­   _ - , ; : ! ¡ ? ¿ . · ' " « » ( ) [ ] { } § ¶ @ * / \ &
# % ` ´ ^ ¯ ¨ ¸ ° © ® + ± ÷ × < = > ¬ | ¦ ~ ¤ ¢ $ £ ¥ 0 1 ¹
½ ¼ 2 ² 3 ³ ¾ 4 5 6 7 8 9 a A ª á Á à À â Â å Å ä Ä ã Ã æ Æ
b B c C ç Ç d D ð Ð e E é É è È ê Ê ë Ë f F g G h H i I í Í
ì Ì î Î ï Ï j J k K l L m M n N ñ Ñ o O º ó Ó ò Ò ô Ô ö Ö õ
Õ ø Ø p P q Q r R s S ß t T u U ú Ú ù Ù û Û ü Ü v V w W x X
y Y ý Ý ÿ z Z þ Þ µ
```

Comment: The function to generate `x` is quite interesting :) nice answer!