# R - In apply function, logical always evaluates to false when data is integer, but evaluates correctly when integer is character

Tags: r

In R, I am trying to run an apply function on a column (a) in a dataframe and putting the result in a new column (b). The column (c) is of integer class and consists of integers 0 - 5.

My code is:

```
df$b <- apply(df, 1, FUN = function (x) if (x["a"] == 0) x["b"] = "a"
else if (x["a"] == 1) x["b"] = "b"
else if (x["a"] == 2) x["b"] = "c" 
else if (x["a"] == 3) x["b"] = "d" 
else if (x["a"] == 4) x["b"] = "e" 
else x["b"] = "f")
```

When column a is of class integer, all the logicals fail so all rows in column b are assigned "f". However, when I change column a to character class using `as.character()`, the logicals evaluate correctly. Why is this the case?

Comment: please share you data so we can help. most likel you will need `ifelse()` here and not apply/if statements

Comment: Your code works fine here with `df <- data.frame(a = as.integer(c(0,1,2,3,4)))`. Please provide some data where it fails and some more info on what you're trying to do. This might not be the right way.

Comment: Yes, that code works fine. The specific function I was using is: ```df$column2 <- apply(df, 1, FUN = function (x) if (x["column1"] == 0) x["column2"] = "Zero" else if (x["column1"] == 1 | x["column1"] == 2) x["column2"] = "One" else if (x["column1"] == 3 | x["column1"] == 4) x["column2"] = "Two" else x["column2"] = "Three")``` When I run ```table(df$column2)```, all the rows have value "Three". Running ```class(df$column1)``` return integer. ```ifelse()``` performs the logical correctly, i.e. does not set everything to the "else" value, but I'm confused why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From the R Docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/R.utils/versions/2.11.0/topics/isZero)

> Note that x == 0 will not work in all cases.

This (I believe, please correct me if I'm wrong) is because the values you have in your comparisons are [R numeric types](http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/basic-data-types/numeric#:%7E:text=Decimal%20values%20are%20called%20numerics,will%20be%20of%20numeric%20type.&text=Furthermore%2C%20even%20if%20we%20assign,saved%20as%20a%20numeric%20value.). You can verify this by running:

```
# Assign an integer value to y
y = 5
 
# print the class name of variable
print(class(y))
```

The numeric type of a value is not equal to the integer type of the value, but when you convert it into a character, the R comparison automatically converts the value [to a numeric for you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57348280/comparing-strings-to-numeric), using the unicode values of the character vector.

This specific code can be repaired in multiple ways. For what you seem to be doing, an apply function similar to the following might be a more readable solution:

```
values <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")
df$b <- ifelse( a > 4, "f", values[a + 1])
```

See the vectorized [`ifelse` documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/ifelse)

Comment: Is there a reason why ifelse works but using apply does not? When I tried ```print(class(df$a))```, I get a class integer

Comment: `df$a` is an integer, the literal values you typed in are interpreted by R as numerics. The reason that `ifelse` works and not `apply`, is that `ifelse` uses the `>` operator rather than the `==` operator. You could write an `apply` statement that uses `>` which would also work, but in R [vectorized operations](https://bookdown.org/rdpeng/rprogdatascience/vectorized-operations.html) like `ifelse` run efficiently in parallel, so it's good practice to use them when possible.

Comment: I see, so numeric and integers are two different classes? Is the ```>``` operator just a greater than operator? I was using ```apply``` because I needed an "else if". Is there an ```ifelse``` version?

Comment: @grapeporcupine, the `>` operator is just greater. You can have an else-if option by nesting `ifelse`. (`ifelse(x>4, "f", ifelse(x<3, "ifelse fired", "neither true))`)