# Comparing numeric and characters in R

Tags: r

Just wondering aloud, why would this be? I expected to be given may be a warning... Any idea?

```
library(dplyr)

mytibble <- tibble(
  a = c("0", "8", "0", "1", "0", "23", "54")
)

mytibble %>% 
  filter(a<13)
```

Behind the scene , `"0" <13` is TRUE right??

Comment: Sorry about that I misstyped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't comparison between numeric and character variables give a warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009936/why-doesnt-comparison-between-numeric-and-character-variables-give-a-warning)